# Jquery datepicker month select

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
<form name="searchForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/sales/list_month/" onsubmit="return search_date_check();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="testDatepicker3" name="search_date" style="width:80px;" value="<?php echo $search_date; ?>">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">검색</button>
  </div>
</form>

$(function() {
    $( "#testDatepicker3" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm",
    monthNames: ['1월','2월','3월','4월','5월','6월','7월','8월','9월','10월','11월','12월'],
    dayNamesMin: ['일','월','화','수','목','금','토']
    });
});
```

how to show selected month.

1. select February in testDatepicker3
2. Form submit ( input value = 2015-02 )
3. select again testDatepicker3
4. Why don't display February. It shown currently month ( March )

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate this might help

Comment: `var curr_date = new Date($("#testDatepicker3").val()+"-01");
$(function() {
    $( "#testDatepicker3" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm",
    defaultDate: curr_date,
    monthNames: ['1월','2월','3월','4월','5월','6월','7월','8월','9월','10월','11월','12월'],
    dayNamesMin: ['일','월','화','수','목','금','토']
    });
});`